# Select2 if first option selected disable the rest

Tags: jquery-select2

I have this select2 where

- If first option is selected, **all other options should be disabled.**
- If any other option is selected, **first option should be disabled.**

Any help?

```
<select class="select2">
<option value="Package">Complete Package</option>
<option value="Hotel">Hotel Only</option>
<option value="Transport">Transport Only</option>
<option value="Misc">Misc</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Library select2
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css
**reference fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/hpkqxto6/

    <select multiple id="example" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="Package">Complete Package</option>
    <option value="Hotel">Hotel Only</option>
    <option value="Transport">Transport Only</option>
    <option value="Misc">Misc</option>
    </select>
    
    $(function() {
        $('#example').select2();
    
        //Select2 Event handler for selecting an item
        $('#example').on("select2:selecting", function(evt, f, g) {
          disableSel2(evt, this, true);
        });
    
        // Select2 Event handler for unselecting an item
        $('#example').on("select2:unselecting", function(evt) {
          disableSel2(evt, this, false);
        });
      });
      // At some point during the select2 instantation it created the 
      // data object it needs with the source select option.
      // This function, called by the events above to set the current status for the
      // group for which the selected option belongs.
      function disableSel2(evt, target, disabled) {
        // Found a note in the Select2 formums on how to get the item to be selected
        var selId = evt.params.args.data.id;
        var aaList = $("option", target);
        $.each(aaList, function(idx, item) {
          var data = $(item).data("data");
          if (selId == "Package") {
            if(data.id != selId){
            data.disabled = disabled;
              $('#example > option').prop("selected", false);
            }
          } 
        })
      }
```